# add an object from bpy.data.objects in context scene?

Tags: python, scripting, linked-data

i'd like to "append" a deleted objects that is stuck inside bpy.data.objects via python in the context scene, how to do so?

right now, i'm creating a new object and doing something like that

```
    stuck = bpy.data.objects['my_hidden_obj']

    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add()
    New = bpy.context.object
    New.data = stuck.data
    New.name = stuck.name
```

but i'm almost sure there's a way better technique to do so ? correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Link to collection**

```
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(stuck)
```

or for < 2.8 link to scene

```
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(stuck)
```

Comment: of course ! linking to scene collection !
Thanks